# Laravel storage exists() returns false for file names with spaces

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

I'm trying to check if file exists using `storage exists()` function.

This function returns `true` if file name doesn't have `spaces` but `false` otherwise.

I'm trying to use Storage facades code as follows

```php
if (Storage::disk("local")->exists($model->path)) { // path of the file 
    Storage::move(); // logic to move files
}
```

> Storage folders has all permissions

I have lot of files with `spaces` in my storage `subfolder F1`. I want to move those file to another `subfolder F2` inside storage itself. It would be tedious to rename each and every file for `exists()` to work.

---

**Update**

Php inbuilt `file_exists()` works for same path i.e it returns `true` if file is found and even if it has `spaces` in it's name.

Code for `file_exists()`

```php
file_exists(storage_path() . '/app/F1/Demo One.pdf');
```

I have used tinker for debugging.

Why storage facades `exists()` returns `false`?

Answer (score -1):

storage_path() and the local Storage disk have different base directories

storage_path() base directory is 'storage'

Storage::disk('local') base directory is 'storage/app'

Comment: if I do `Storage::disk('local)->path(F1/Demo One.pdf)` and `file_exists(storage_path() . '/F1/Demo One.pdf');` both outputs have same path. Why 1st is not working but 2nd is working in if condition?

Comment: They are not the same path, the first will equate to 'storage/app/F1/Demo One.pdf' the 2nd will equate to 'storage/F1/Demo One.pdf' notice the 'app' in the first one, as the local disk route is 'storage/app' and not 'storage'

Comment: Sorry I mistyped `file_exists` its actually `file_exists(storage_path() . '/app/F1/Demo One.pdf');` . I'm using tinker to check output for both functions. Updated Question

Comment: `Storage::disk("local")->exists('F1/Demo one.pdf');` returns false whereas `file_exists(storage_path() . '/app/F1/Demo one.pdf');` returns true

Comment: Ok, I have just done this and both return true, both have spaces.  Have you changed the default local config and is the casing the same?

Storage::disk('local')->exists('F1/RR logo.png');

file_exists(storage_path() . '/app/F1/RR logo.png');

Comment: I have same casing. I didn't understand default local config part.. what you mean?